# How can I use having without group by?

Tags: oracle, group-by, having

I am reading about [`having`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html) clause in oracle.

It is written in the docs that

> If there is no GROUP BY clause, the HAVING clause is applied to the
>   entire result as a single group.

But whenever I tried to use `having` clause without `group by`, I am getting syntax error.

How can I use `having` without `group by`?

Can somebody explain me with this schema?

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21535)

Comment: using having without group by, equal with WHERE

Comment: @Mehmet: at least in oracle, this is not correct.

Comment: This statement gives a syntax error: SELECT * FROM dual having dummy = 'x';

Answer (score 2):

A simple experiment will prove that this is possible:

```
select * from dual having 1=1
```

This query will run successfully in Oracle 11g. I suspect the problem you're seeing is that you're trying to use an aggregate function in the `having` clause and that is not allowed with a `group by` clause.

While it's clearly possible to use `having` without `group by`, I don't really see any point. Any condition you would put in the `having` clause in this scenario would be more appropriate in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is valid. But also consider below points.

> If there is no GROUP BY clause, the HAVING clause is applied to the entire result as a single group.
>
> booleanExpression in HAVING can contain only grouping columns, columns that are part of aggregate expressions, and columns that are part of a subquery.

So when you are using `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` the following syntaxes are not valid.

```
1) SELECT col_x ....       /* Since col_x is not a part of GROUP BY
```

or

```
2) HAVING col_x (in a boolean expression)  /* Since col_x is not a part of GROUP BY
```

What instead of `col_x` in  you can have is some Aggregate Function on col_x, or a constant, at both HAVING and SELECT clause.

Do not assume the whole table as one group means `GROUP BY col_1, ....col_n`